# Using a pow(2) var for error, convert to readable codes

Tags: php

I know it's possible, but it is doing my head in.

Imagine having an array of codes with their description.

```
array(
0 => "Success",
1 => "File Not Found",
2 => "Could not create file",
4 => "Directory not found",
8 => "Directory could not be created",
16 => "Disk damaged"
)
```

(Don't mind the error codes in the example, I just made them up.)

When getting an error code 1 is easy to resolve. 
Now imagine getting an error code which is "7', I need it to return all options within that error code. So 7 is made out of "4 + 2 + 1".

Hope my question is clear. It's almost like putting an error code level in php.
Where it accumulates the errors together.

Comment: Time to start learning about binary operators

Comment: You can start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of different ways you can do this. Here is one that converts the number to binary and iterates over the digits:

```
function number_to_sum_of_powers($number) {
    $binary = strrev(decbin($number));
    $power = 1;
    $summands = array();
    foreach(str_split($binary) as $digit) {
        if($digit === '1') {
            $summands[] = $power;
        }
        $power *= 2;
    }
    return $summands;
}
```

This is the result when calling it with `7`:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Comment: why did it not come to mind to convert it to binary first. Thanks, works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do that by powers of 2 i.e. the basic Math way, in php

```
   <?php 
        $array = array(
        0 => "Success",
        1 => "File Not Found",
        2 => "Could not create file",
        4 => "Directory not found",
        8 => "Directory could not be created",
        16 => "Disk damaged"
        );

        $total_code = 7; 
        $error_code = 1; 

        while($total_code >= 1){
             if($total_code % 2 == 1){
                  echo $array[$error_code]."<br>";
              }
              $total_code /= 2;
              $error_code *= 2;
       }
   ?>
```

In Java

```
    HashMap<Integer,String> errors = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    errors.put(0, "Success");
    errors.put(1, "File Not Found");
    errors.put(2, "Could not create file");
    errors.put(4, "Directory not found");
    errors.put(8, "Directory could not be created");
    errors.put(16, "Disk damaged");

    int total_code = 7;
    int error_code = 1;

    while(total_code >= 1) {
        if(total_code % 2 == 1)
            System.out.println(errors.get(error_code));
        total_code /= 2;
        error_code *= 2;
    }
```